# Мозги у тебя сыроваты (?) из сыра и ваты

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие, двоеточие-тире

Тире или двоеточие?

`Мозги у тебя сыроваты (?) из сыра и ваты.`

Comment: И запятой хватит.

Comment: Не, пауза стоит на месте скобок, нужно тире или двоеточие.

Comment: Какой смысл в этом изречении: так, приговорка. Запятая присоединительная, тоже паузу обозначает. Куда больше-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поставить любой знак:

1. *Мозги у тебя сыровАты, из сыра и вАты.*

**Запятая.** Это скорее шутка, забавная приговорка.

2. ***МозгИ** у тебя сыроваты — из сыра и вАты. Мозги у тебя **сыровАты**: из сыра и вАты.*

**Тире или двоеточие** (присоединение или пояснение). Это уже заявление посерьезнее.  МозгИ нехороши. Мозги вот такИе.

Comment: Если присоединение, то двоеточие возможно?

Comment: Присоединение – тире, пояснение – двоеточие. Есть разница: понижение тона в обоих случаях, но при двоеточие понижение голоса неполное, а пауза больше.  Так выглядит интонационное предупреждение (материал по учебнику Кустовой для БСП).

Answer (score 0):

Мозги у тебя сыроваты, в их составе сыр и вата.
Допустим, пропущено слово "состав", поэтому ставим тире.
Можно и для паузы тире поставить: мозги у тебя сыроваты - в их составе сыр и вата.